# Do we really need the "visited or not" info of a vertex in Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

In  [Dijkstra's algorithm on Wikipedia (older version, now corrected by me)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dijkstra%27s_algorithm&oldid=626530538#Using_a_priority_queue), the implementation with priority queue will check `vertex` is visited or not before check the shorter path.

Is it really necessary? or even correct?

```
function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
      dist[source] ← 0                      // Initialization
      for each vertex v in Graph:           
          if v ≠ source
              dist[v] ← infinity            // Unknown distance from source to v
              prev[v] ← undefined           // Predecessor of v
          end if
          Q.add_with_priority(v,dist[v])
      end for 


     while Q is not empty:               // The main loop
         u ← Q.extract_min()               // Remove and return best vertex
         mark u as scanned
         for each neighbor v of u:
             if v is not yet scanned: // **is this in need?**
                 alt = dist[u] + length(u, v) 
                 if alt < dist[v]
                     dist[v] ← alt
                     prev[v] ← u
                     Q.decrease_priority(v,alt)
                 end if
             end if
         end for
     end while
     return prev[]
```

I think checking `v is scanned already or not` will prevent any chances in the future if `v`'s path need to be updated.

---

Update:

I've edited the page and the [current Dijkstra's algorithm wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dijkstra%27s_algorithm&oldid=646408018#Using_a_priority_queue) is now correct.

Comment: What about cycles in the graph?

Comment: cycles do not matter because it won't travel the same node ever again. Please note `all nodes are added to queue in beginning` and never be added again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag is not needed. Just look at this section of pseudocode:

```
if v is not yet scanned:
    alt = dist[u] + length(u, v) 
    if alt < dist[v]
         dist[v] ← alt
         prev[v] ← u
         Q.decrease_priority(v,alt)
    end if
end if
```

If you check the different parts:

- `alt` seems to be a local variable that is only used as temporary here, so writing to it doesn't make any difference anywhere else.
- If `v` was already removed from the queue, the path to it was at most as long as the path to `u`, otherwise `u` would have been extracted first.
- If `v` was visited, then `dist[v] <= dist[u] <= alt`. In that case the comparison `alt < dist[v]` is false and the rest of the code is skipped anyways.

Just to explain a bit more, think about the role of the priority queue. It contains the nodes, ordered by the *shortest known path* to them. When extracting a node from the queue, all nodes before where at most as far away as that node and all nodes after will be at least as far away as that node. Since all nodes that were closer were already processed, any new path discovered to one of these nodes there will be via a node that is at least as far away. This means that there can't be any shorter route to an extracted node coming from a node that is still in the queue, so the mere check `alt < dist[v]` will already exclude those nodes that were scanned.

Answer (score -2):

It is require to check V is scanned already or not.

At first cycle we find the vertex(V1) which is minimum cost of neighbor vertexes of source vertex(S1).

At Second cycle, we should not reverse back to the source vertex(S1) from vertex(V1).

Reverse back to the source Vertex (S1) occurs when length(S1,V1) is minimum of neighbor cost vertex(V1).

Code without checking V scanned or not will result in loop for certain case.

Comment: even if reversing back to `S1`, it doesn't matter because the code doesn't add `S1` back to the queue. Also, the distance of `S1` to the source `S` won't be affected.

Comment: line: for each neighbor v of u   - for vertex(V1) - S1 is also neighbor, so it will get reverse.

Comment: then? even if `s1` is `v`'s neighbour, what harm it will do?

Comment: if cost of (S1,V1) is less of all other Neighbours of V1 , it will consider as next shortest path to destination and come to starting point S1.

Comment: It won't because S1 has been removed already as S1 must be before V1, right? Please note, it is not a standard BFS as if standard, nodes are added to Queue dynamically. Here all nodes have been added to the queue at the very beginning and they will be removed as being extracted, but never will be added to queue again.

Comment: There is no such line to remove S1 from vertex set. if such line occurs you argument can be accepted.

Comment: `u ← Q.extract_min()               // Remove and return best vertex` here is the line. if you say from S1 to V1, then S1 must have been extracted and removed before.

Comment: Yes , I agree. Proceeding to next cycle, V2 is selected from Neighbour of V1, at that time V1 is not removed from vertex set. at that time it will create problem.

Comment: V1 is immediately removed after we obtain it. Pls read the code carefully